# Is there any possibility to pass text between react component tags?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering if it is possible in react to pass data between two React component tags

Example:

**Component.js**

```
var React = require('react');

export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return /*some text*/;
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
/*rendered to page*/
<MyComponent>How do I display this text?</MyComponent>
```

I know I could just add `this.props.text` but just curious if that's an option

Answer (score 70):

You can use `this.props.children`:

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
    }
}
```

And then write it as a JSX element:

```
<MyComponent>How do I display this text?</MyComponent>
```

Answer (score 15):

Similar to Danny Delott's answer, except simpler with a function component and props destructuring.

```
export default function MyComponent({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>{children}</div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like @danny-delott's answer, but you can use [React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) if you don't want an extra nested div:

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <>{this.props.children}</>
    }
}
```

Alternatively, one might want to set the "display" property to "contents" to prevent the div from affecting the nested text.

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div style={{display:"contents"}}>{this.props.children}</div>
    }
}
```